# Conditional probability p(y|x) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

How to calculate conditional probability in vendor agnostic SQL code while reading a precomputed table (*histogram*) just once?

Let's imagine we have a query which returns a *histogram* relation. The *histogram* contains following attributes: {*x*, *y*, *cnt*}, where *cnt* is the count of occurrences of nominal attributes *x* and *y*. And calculation of the *histogram* is time consuming.

Once we have the *histogram*, we want to calculate conditional probability *p(y|x)*. A possible way how to do that is to take *p(y|x) = count(y,x) / count(x)* as outlined in the following query:

```
with histogram as (
    // Long and time consuming subquery returning {x, y, cnt}
), x_count as (
    select x
         , sum(cnt) as cnt
    from histogram
    group by x
) 
select y
     , x
     , cnt/x_count.cnt as probability 
from histogram 
join x_count
using(x)
```

However, common table expressions (CTEs) are not portable (e.g. MySQL does not work with them). Is there a way how to rewrite the CTE that:

1. The same query can be executed without change at MySQL, MSSQL and PostgreSQL?
2. Relation *histogram* is calculated just once?

All I can think of is to materialize the *histogram* into a table. Process the *histogram*. And delete the *histogram*.

Comment: in MariaDB Version 10.2.1 you can use CTEs : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/

Comment: @BerndBuffen - Nice! MySQL has support for CTEs from version 8.0.0 as well: http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/

Answer (score 2):

First, just because you declare something as a CTE does not mean that it is run only once.  For instance, SQL Server does not materialize CTEs, so using your logic it would run the histogram once for each reference.  It is the same as a view.

In addition, the `using` clause is not supported by all databases.

So, the one thing that you could do that is vendor agnostic is to use a view.  There is a slight hitch, because dropping a view that already exists is vendor-specific.  But the following would generally work to *express* the query:

```
create view histogram as  -- you might want to give this a more unique name
    // Long and time consuming subquery returning {x, y, cnt}

select h.y, h.x, cnt / total.cnt as probability 
from histogram h join
     (select x, sum(cnt) as cnt
      from histogram
      group by x
     ) total
     on h.x = total.x;

drop view histogram;
```

Of course, this runs the histogram query multiple times.  So, you *could* solve this using temporary tables:

```
create table histogram (
    x ??,  -- I don't know what the types are
    y ??,
    cnt ??
);

insert into histogram (x, y, cnt)
    select . . . ;  -- your complicated query here

select y, x, cnt * 1.0 / total.cnt as probability 
from histogram h join
     (select x, sum(cnt) as cnt
      from histogram
      group by x
     ) total
     on h.x = total.x;

drop table histogram;
```

Unfortunately, dropping an *existing* table is database specific.  This does meet your requirements, though.

My advice would be to drop MySQL from the requirement -- it is rather degraded from the perspective of ANSI functionality.  Then simply do:

```
select h.*, cnt * 1.0 / sum(cnt) over (partition by x) as probability
from histogram h;
```

(The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division and `cnt` sounds like it might be an integer.)

This would be the simplest way to represent the query without re-calculating `histogram`.  And, it will work in a lot of databases -- SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, Teradata, DB2, BigQuery, RedShift, Hive.  In fact, I think it will work in pretty much all current versions of what is commonly called a "database" except MySQL, SQLite, and MS Access.